# How to solve duplicated lists in numpy 1.24?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Now I have a 2-dimensional list which have many duplicated lists in it：

```
sta_list = [[31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], ……, [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [34, 33, 1, 0], ……]
```

In numpy 1.22, I can use np.unique to remove duplicated lists like this:

```
np.unique(np.array(sta_lists))
```

But in numpy 1.24, it can only get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yy\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\plugins\python\helpers-pro\pydevd_asyncio\pydevd_asyncio_utils.py", line 114, in _exec_async_code
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (396,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

So how to solve the problem in python 3.11 and numpy 1.24 rather than retreating to older python and numpy？

Comment: It's a nested list, but not a 2d one, at least not one that can be turned into a 2d array.  Sublists differ in length.  That's what the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy gives you the answer when running it under 1.22.

`VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.`

So let's try it with setting `dtype='object'`:

```
>>> np.unique(np.array(sta_list, dtype='object'))
array([list([31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0]), list([34, 33, 1, 0])], dtype=object)
```

It works as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`. Convert the 2-dimensional list into a set of tuples, where each inner list becomes a unique tuple. Then convert the set back into a list of lists.

```
import numpy as np

sta_list = [[31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [34, 33, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0]]

unique_sta_list = list(set(tuple(row) for row in sta_list))
print(unique_sta_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[(34, 33, 1, 0), (31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score -1):

In NumPy 1.24, the behavior of np.unique has changed, requiring homogeneous input arrays. Consequently, directly applying np.unique to a list of lists, such as sta_list, results in a ValueError due to the input being heterogeneous.

A workaround is to utilize Python's built-in set data structure, which automatically removes duplicates. By converting the inner lists to tuples (as tuples are hashable and can be elements of sets), we can efficiently remove duplicate lists while preserving the order. Here's the code:

```py
sta_list = [[31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0], [34, 33, 1, 0], [31, 30, 11, 3, 1, 0]]

unique_lists = [list(t) for t in set(tuple(lst) for lst in sta_list)]

## for testing purpose ##
print(unique_lists)
```

This code snippet converts each inner list into a tuple, which is then used to create a set. Since sets cannot contain duplicate elements, the duplicates are automatically removed. Finally, the unique tuples are converted back to lists, providing the desired unique lists as the output.